# Strict mode forbids implicit creation of global property 'inferred'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, karma-jasmine

I keep getting the following error when i build

Karma Run Failed: undefined

```
ERROR [karma]: ReferenceError: Strict mode forbids implicit creation of global property 'inferred'
at undefined:9
```

It does not tell me where it occurs or which property it just refers to inferred.

Comment: Search through your code for 'inferred =' without the quotes and add `var` in front of it.

Comment: Thats the thing i cant  cant find the string inferred in the code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use a global variable without initializing it.
Try to find this variable in the code and declare it before use.

```
let inferred;
inferred = ...;
```

If you cannot find this variable, then most likely it is a property of some object that is undefined

Comment: Thanks, i searched the git repo and there is no found references to inferred, that's why i assumed that it was some type of weird error, i have seen answers where it refers to the property then you add a var or a let and it then works...

Comment: any ideas how to find this property?